# Creating meeting never creates a meeting

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have the following code to create a meeting in exchange:

```
        _exchangeService = new ExchangeService
        {
            Url = EwsUrl,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password)
        };

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(_exchangeService);
        appointment.Subject = "New meeting";
        appointment.Start = start;
        appointment.End = end;
        await appointment.Save();
```

This all goes through without error being thrown in code, however when I look at my calendar, no meeting has been created.

Can anyone suggest any reason why this might be, or what I can do to fix this?

Comment: does await appointment.Save(); return a code or any other result?

Comment: No it doesn't return a response.

Answer (score 0):

In the `appointment.Save()` method, you have to specify a sending mode.

For example: `appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone)`.

Furthermore you could try

```
appointment.Save(WellknownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

which will save a copy of the meeting into your calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, this still doesn't create the appointment

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, that it always creates a meeting instead of an appointment. Due to the fact i didn't add an attendee.

I found the solution here! I have to save with the parameter "SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone".

```
appointment.save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```